# Dynamic links with displaytag

Tags: java, jsp, displaytag

```
<display:table id="row" name="userList" requestURI="">
    <display:column href="user.do?action=view&user=${row.id}" class="details">Details</display:column>
</display:table>
```

I'm trying to send to the user.do servlet a query like **action=view&user=23**.
The method posted here passes as row.id just the id from the first user in the list. Even though I have 5 users and I press Details for the last one, it still passes the id of the first user.

I have the EL active.

What is the correct approach for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert but did you map your list with the id in your controller?
something like this.....

Account acct =  null;

String selectedID = (String)request.getAttribute("targetID");

if (selectedID != null) {

acct.setUserList(userListDAO.getUserList.getId());

}else {

logger.error(" List is null" +selectedID);

}

where target ID points to another attribute which is set to the user ID....
as I said I'm no expert but I'm just trying to give in my 2 cents....

Thanks